# timestamp with time zone mapped to LocalDateTime instead of OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, java-time

It seems that the new Java time feature in jooq 3.9 maps postgresql's `timestamp with time zone` to `LocalDateTime` whereas I would expect an `OffsetDateTime.`

Is that expected?

---

Example: I have a postgres table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE so_table (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  ts timestamp with time zone
);
```

I include `<javaTimeTypes>true</javaTimeTypes>` in my pom and the generated class includes this method:

```
public LocalDateTime getTs() {
    return (LocalDateTime) get(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that expected?

Yes and no. Unfortunately, in version 3.9, the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type support is not yet included in the code generator: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5734

Comment: I missed that issue - thanks. And good work anyway for this new feature :-)

Comment: So out of the [#4429](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4429) presentation, `LocalDate => DATE`, `LocalTime => TIME`, `LocalDateTime => TIMESTAMP`, `OffsetTime => TIME_WITH_TIMEZONE`, `OffsetDateTime => TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE`, everything has been implemented but the last one, right?

Comment: @assylias: But the last two